# Git GC mechanism - does it matter if tag annotated or lightweight

Tags: git

[This page](http://think-like-a-git.net/sections/graphs-and-git/garbage-collection.html) says the following:

> Eventually, Git will decide that it's time to run garbage collection.
>   (You can trigger this process yourself, using git gc.) Starting from
>   every branch and **every tag**, Git walks back through the graph, building
>   a list of every commit it can reach. Once it's reached the end of
>   every path, it deletes all the commits it didn't visit.

Does it look for annotated or lightweight tags?

I'm working without branches with tagging commits and just curios if there's any chance my commits will be garbage collected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cited reference does say **every tag**, which already implies that both lightweight and annotated tags are taken into account. The authoritative source is the `git-gc` [man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc), which states it like this:

> *git gc* tries very hard not to delete objects that are referenced anywhere in your repository. In particular, it will keep not only objects referenced by your current set of branches and tags, but also objects referenced by the index, remote-tracking branches, refs saved by *git filter-branch* in refs/original/, or reflogs (which may reference commits in branches that were later amended or rewound). If you are expecting some objects to be deleted and they aren’t, check all of those locations and decide whether it makes sense in your case to remove those references.

In other words, `git` is very careful to err on the side of caution and avoid deleting *anything* that might be considered useful. Deleting objects reachable through tags created by the user himself would constitute an extremely serious data loss bug.

Comment: yeah, it makes sense, gl